# Chrome HTML5 medium canceled download

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-video, mp4, mediaelement.js

I'm having serious problems with Google Chrome.

I'm using MediaElement.js for audio and video playback. Firefox seems to play everything fine, so far.

Chrome doesn't. As soon, as the file becomes bigger, it won't play.

I have two test files. Both Mp4. The first one plays well in Chrome:

```
Request Headers:  

Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection: keep-alive
DNT: 1
Range: bytes=0-
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36

Response Headers:  

Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-control: max-age=31536000, private
Connection: keep-alive
Content-disposition: attachment; filename="big_buck_bunny.mp4"
Content-Length: 5510872
Content-Type: video/mp4
Date: Mon, 24 Feb 2014 04: 13: 40 GMT
ETag: "24"
Expires: Tue, 24 Feb 2015 04: 13: 39 GMT
Last-Modified: Sat, 22 Feb 2014 16: 28: 14 GMT
Server: nginx
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1~dotdeb.1
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

The 2nd one doesn't:

```
Request Headers: 

Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
DNT: 1
Range: bytes=0-
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36

Response Headers: 

Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-control: max-age=31536000, private
Connection: keep-alive
Content-disposition: attachment; filename="test.mp4"
Content-Length: 21546967
Content-Type: video/mp4
Date: Mon, 24 Feb 2014 04: 11: 29 GMT
ETag: "31"
Expires: Tue, 24 Feb 2015 04: 11: 29 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 24 Feb 2014 03: 23: 48 GMT
Server: nginx
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1~dotdeb.1
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

On Google, i found several discussions regarding this or similar problems. However, i havent found a real solution for this problem.

Another (maybe important) info is, that i serve the files via PHP. If i use the direct URL of the file, it works:

```
Request Headers:   

Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection: keep-alive
DNT: 1
If-Range: "9c0c52-148c7d7-4f31e800012d1"
Range: bytes=21510441-21546966
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36

Response Headers:   

Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 36526
Content-Range: bytes 21510441-21546966/21546967
Date: Mon, 24 Feb 2014 04: 19: 03 GMT
ETag: "9c0c52-148c7d7-4f31e800012d1"
Last-Modified: Mon, 24 Feb 2014 03: 23: 48 GMT
Server: nginx
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested several scenarios now. This seems to be a general problem. Streaming media files via PHP doesn't work properly. The only reliable way is to stream the files via webserver.